# Ruby on Rails gsub doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
            txt = "I'm happy :)"     #This is input from user
            txt = txt.gsub("'","\\'")
            raise :test
```

I'm getting "Im happy :)m happy :)"

I want to get this string variable's value is "I\'m happy :)" (with one backslash)

I'm using Rails. I will use this string variable to parameter for this situation I cannot use "puts" method. I tried many methods(%W(...), %(...)) to solve but I couldn't it yet.

Answer (score 1):

`\'` is interpreted as the string to the right of the match, so it is doing what it should (see [regex match context](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecontext.html)).

to do what you want you can do

```
gsub("'","\\\\'"}
```

or

```
gsub("'") { |s| "\\'" }
```